# Delayed confirmation button animation

Tags: android, button, wear-os

I have a DelayedConfirmationView in a Framelayout:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.wearable.view.DelayedConfirmationView
    android:id="@+id/delayed_confirmation"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:src="@drawable/save_button"
    app:circle_color="@color/blue"
    app:circle_radius="45dp"
    app:circle_radius_pressed="40dp"
    app:circle_padding="5dp"
    app:circle_border_width="10dp"
    app:circle_border_color="@color/white"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:text="Save"
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp" />
</FrameLayout>
```

This layout is intended to be displayed by a fragment:

```
public class SaveRunFragment extends Fragment implements DelayedConfirmationView.DelayedConfirmationListener {
Run1Fragment run1;
private DelayedConfirmationView mDelayedView;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_saverun, container, false);

    mDelayedView =
            (DelayedConfirmationView) view.findViewById(R.id.delayed_confirmation);
    mDelayedView.setTotalTimeMs(4 * 1000);
    mDelayedView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            System.out.println("START");
            mDelayedView.start();
            mDelayedView.setListener(SaveRunFragment.this);
            return;
        }
    });

    return view;
}

@Override
public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();
}

@Override
public void onTimerFinished(View view) {
    System.out.println("END");
}

@Override
public void onTimerSelected(View view) {
    System.out.println("cancel");
}
}
```

I want to implement an animation on the button like the one that is on the delayedconfirmation developer guides: https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/ui/confirm.html
but when I click the button the onclick() doesn't trigger the action.

I've tested it making a different button to trigger that action, but all that happens is that the prints are shown but the little margin around the button is not displayed...

Can someone tell me what am I doing wrong?

**EDIT**

So I've changed my fragment to this:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_saverun, container, false);

    System.out.println("before");
    mDelayedView =
            (DelayedConfirmationView) view.findViewById(R.id.delayed_confirmation);
    mDelayedView.setTotalTimeMs(4000);
    mDelayedView.setListener(this);
    System.out.println("after");

    return view;
}

@Override
public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();
}

@Override
public void onTimerFinished(View view) {
    //delayed confirmation
    System.out.println("END");
}

@Override
public void onTimerSelected(View v) {
    System.out.println("SELECTED");
    if (animation == false) {
        mDelayedView.start();
        mDelayedView.setListener(this);
        animation = true;
        System.out.println("Start");
    } else {
        ((DelayedConfirmationView) v).setListener(null);
        animation = false;
        System.out.println("Cancel");
    }
}
```

the prints are shown as expected but there is no animation around the circular button...

**EDIT**

The problem was that my source image was to big and it was covering the animation and that was why it didn't show up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have set an `OnClickListener` on the DelayedConfirmationView itself; you shouldn't do that since it will not receive the touch events. It is common to start the count down by providing another component (say a button) so that user can click on that to start. The "onTimerSelected()" callback is called whenever user clicks on the DelayedConfirmationView, whether the counter has started or not (in the source for that component, the onTouchEvent() is used to receive the touch events and it delegates them to onTimerStart()) so your onCreateView() should change to be like:

```
    ...
    mDelayedView = (DelayedConfirmationView) 
                   findViewById(R.id.delayed_confirmation);
    mDelayedView.setListener(this);
    mDelayedView.setTotalTimeMs(4000);
    ...
```

You can start the countdown by clicking on the same DelayedConfirmationView by calling `mDelayedView.start()` inside `onTimerSelected()` but then you have to manage the state yourself in terms of interpreting that click event as start or cancel depending on the previous state.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! The thing is, after redoing my code with your information, the animation is still not displayed... I want the delayedConfirmationView to show the animation around the circular button when clicked but it only shows the prints and no animation...

Comment: Show your complete modified code; you are probably still missing; I built a sample based on your layout and it worked just fine.

Comment: I've updated my question with the answer. Obviously it was a stupid mistake by me... Thanks for the help!!!